# How to rename css classes using vim

Tags: html, css, vim, refactoring

i want to do some refactor in my web site using vim

i have html file `index.html` and css file `style.css` 
i want to rename some css classes

so when i change

`<div class="XX">
 </div>`

to

`<div class="yy">
</div>`

the css file change automatically from

`.xx{
     color:red;
    }`

to

`.yy{
    color:red;
   }`

how i do that in vim ?

Answer (score 1):

Vim is not an IDE and does not provide any refactor tools. However you can do a find and replace by using a substitution and combined with arglist or quickfix list to accomplish your goals. See the following [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) for more: [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/). Here is an example project wide substitution using `:Cdo` referenced in the vimcast episode.

```
:vimgrep/ClassName/ **/*
:Cdo s/ClassName/SomethingElse/ge|w
```

You may also want to use something faster than `:vimgrep`. You can use the systems's grep via `:grep` or use a faster grepping tool like [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) or [Ag Silver Search](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) via `'grepprg'`. If you are in a git repo then I suggest you use `git grep` or `:Ggrep` if you use [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

You may also want to use the `c` flag for the substitution so you can confirm each substitution.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h arglist
:h :s
:h :s_flags
:h :vimgrep
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
```